# How to search single video instead of whole playlist using youtube v3 api?

Tags: android, api

I'm trying to get single single video using youtube api this is how I'm sending request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=mykey&q=newReleaseSong,latestEnglishSongs&type=video
```

instead of displaying single video it's displaying whole playlists related to my query